# Distinct keyword not fetching results in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query where I unique records for patient_id, meaning patient_id should not be duplicate. Each time I try executing the query, seems like the DB hangs or it takes hours to execute, I'm not sure. I need my records to load quickly. Any quick resolution will be highly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.patient_id, 
      a.study_id, 
      a.procstep_id, 
      a.formdata_seq, 
      0, 
      (SELECT MAX(audit_id) 
      FROM audit_info 
      WHERE patient_id =a.patient_id 
      AND study_id     = a.study_id 
      AND procstep_id  = a.procstep_id 
      AND formdata_seq = a.formdata_seq 
      ) AS data_session_id 
      FROM frm_rg_ps_rg a, 
      PATIENT_STUDY_STEP pss 
      WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM frm_rg_ps_rg b 
      WHERE a.patient_id = b.patient_id 
      AND a.formdata_seq = b.formdata_seq 
      AND a.psdate      IS NOT NULL 
      AND b.psdate      IS NOT NULL 
      AND a.psresult    IS NOT NULL 
      AND b.psresult    IS NOT NULL) = 1) 
      OR NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT * 
      FROM frm_rg_ps_rg c 
      WHERE a.psdate                               IS NOT NULL 
      AND c.psdate                                 IS NOT NULL 
      AND a.psresult                               IS NOT NULL 
      AND c.psresult                               IS NOT NULL 
      AND a.patient_id                              = c.patient_id 
      AND a.formdata_seq                            = c.formdata_seq 
      AND a.elemdata_seq!                           =c.elemdata_seq  
      AND a.psresult                               != c.psresult 
      AND ((SELECT (a.psdate - c.psdate) FROM dual)>=7 
      OR (SELECT (a.psdate - c.psdate) FROM dual)  <=-7) 
      ) 
      AND a.psresult IS NOT NULL 
      AND a.psdate   IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Sounds like you should just rewrite the query entirely.  If you want some assistance, ask *another* question, provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: It keeps executing and fetches nothing. When I remove DISTINCT, I get 3000+ records

Comment: You don't need to check a.psdate and a.psresult for NULL in subqueries, since they are checked in main query. You don't need to select from dual, simple substraction of dates works. You don't have to select data_session_id now, do it it outer query after elimination of duplicate patient_id

Answer (score 0):

For start, you have a cartesian product with `PATIENT_STUDY_STEP` (pss).
It is not connected to anything.

---

```
select  *

from   (select  t.*
               ,count (*) over (partition by patient_id) as cnt

        from    frm_rg_ps_rg t 
        ) t

where   cnt = 1
;
```

Comment: Right, will remove that. But any suggestions to fetch unique records for patient_id?